# Why is $scope.modal undefined when i try to open an ionic template modal?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic-app for iPad.
In one of my templates i have a treeview with items.
When i click on items i want to open other templates modal.
I tried it with one of my templates but i get an error, that $scope.modal in the controller is undefined.

Further, can the loaded template use it's own controller?

This is my controller-code:

```
.controller('SystemValidateCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $ionicModal, ComponentTree, TypeOfTests, TypeOfTestReasons) {
    $scope.showTypeOfTest = function () {
        $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/type-of-test.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });
    };
    $scope.openModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.show();
    };
    $scope.closeModal = function () {
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };
    //Cleanup the modal when we're done with it!
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
    });
    // Execute action on hide modal
    $scope.$on('modal.hidden', function () {
        // Execute action
    });
    // Execute action on remove modal
    $scope.$on('modal.removed', function () {
        // Execute action
    });

    $scope.$on('$ionTreeList:ItemClicked', function (event, item) {
        //TODO: Show the template according to the item.id
        var panel_dynamic = document.getElementById('panel_dynamic_to_treeitem');
        if (panel_dynamic.hasChildNodes()) {
            panel_dynamic.removeChild(panel_dynamic.childNodes[0]);
        }
        var line = document.createElement("div");

        if(item.id == 9999) //Anzeige der Testarten
        {
            $scope.showTypeOfTest();
            $scope.openModal();
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Are you certain that the promise is firing .then?  Meaning, maybe the line $scope.modal = modal isn't executed? It could be failing to load templates/type-of-test.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `fromTemplateUrl` returns a promise,

```
$scope.showTypeOfTest();
$scope.openModal();
```

will not work because modal is not defined due to `$scope.modal = modal;`was not called yet.

suggestion: refactor to chaining promise :

```
showTypeOfTest = function() {
 return $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/type-of-test.html', {
            scope: $scope,
            animation: 'slide-in-up'
        }).then(function (modal) {
            $scope.modal = modal;
        });
}
```

then you can use

```
$scope.showTypeOfTest().then($scope.openModal);
```

Comment: Thank You very much Mephiztopheles. You're absolutely right.

Comment: Can i ask You one more question please? Is it possible that the loaded template uses it's own controller or has all code for the template to be in the controller which is loading?

Comment: Hi Mephiztopheles. I've found it out. The original controller of the template can be passed to it by adding and setting the attribute ng-controller to the ion-content-tag of the template.

Comment: I didn't know the answer to your second question, so i would had to look it up .. but you found it :)